# Wrap inside a row gets cut

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

So I have a column composed of rows, the column has a defined sized and each row takes the space it needs.

[image: The column]

Each row is composed of 2 containers, the right container has a Wrap that wraps items of 50x50 size.
The problem is when there are more than 5 items, the next row gets cut.

```
class MyRow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                  child: Text("Title"),
                )
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                color: Colors.green,

                child: Wrap(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    RowItem(),
                    RowItem(),
                    RowItem(),
                    RowItem(),
                    RowItem(),
                    RowItem(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the main column:

```
class TestShare extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16/9,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                MyRow(),
                MyRow(),
                MyRow(),
                ...
              ],
            )
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Make your list scrollable with listview.builder

Comment: what do you mean by row cuts, can you explain.

Comment: List cannot be scrollable, I want everything to fit in the same aspect ratio. 2: as you can see in the green parte, the second row of black squares doesn't fit inside the green container.